# Download via pip and npm not working

Tags: network-manager, internet, downloads, pip, npm

I am not able to download pip packages or npm packages via terminal. However my browser internet connection is working. I am not sure what is the issue.Please help me to fix it.
I am using Ubuntu22.04

My python program takes almost 1 hr to run. Previously it takes less than a minute. Also when create a new react app it takes too much time to download the app.

Comment: You have provided too little detail on what you actually are trying to achieve...

Comment: When i try to install any library package using pip or npm i am not able to download anything from terminal. However if i open the same library in browser i am able to download it. It takes too much of time to  provide a error response. for example if i want to download pandas using pip or react library using npm it takes almost an hour to show the error output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When i tried to ping any site using IPv4 i am able to connect to the site. If i ping the same site using IPV6 it stop after the first ping. so i disabled IPV6 in the system settings. After restarting now i am able to use pip and npm. IF any one know why its working in IPV4 and not working in IPV6 kindly explain.